# sequence of inequalities information theory

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

[image: y]

can you please give a hint about how to solve this problem ?

Comment: To warm up: Some easy questions you should (might) already have asked yourself, to check we understand the problem . 1) how many terms have that sum ? 2) can we prove the inequalities if the variables are iid ?

Comment: Assume that $n=4 , k = 3 then \alpha = \{1,3,4\} and \beta = \{1,4\} L= 3$ $H(X_{\alpha}) = H(X_{\beta} ) + H(X_L |X_{\beta}) where |\beta|=k-1, \alpha = \beta \cup \{L\}$ Then, $H(X_1,X_3,X_4) = H(X_1,X_4) + H(X_3|X_1,X_4)$ we should use the theorem $H(X_1,X_2) + H(X_2,X_3) + H(X_1,X_3) ≥ 2H(X_1,X_2,X_3).$ and $H(X_1,X_2,X_3) = H(X_j, j= i) + H(X_i | X_j, j = i)$
for $i = 1, 2, 3$ to complete the proof but I stuck

Comment: Hint: just try to prove $H_n \le H_{n-1}.$ The natural proof you come up with can be generalised to give the following lemma: for any non-empty set $S \subset [1:n],$ $$ H(X_S) \le \frac{1}{|S| -1} \sum_{i \in S} H(X_{S - \{i\}} ).$$

Now try to use this lemma to show $H_{k+1} \le H_k$ for any $k$.